# Meaning of the following statement in a situation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Meaning of following statement:

> Person A: Even if you are hurt just leave it all to God, that is it. That is why I can forgive and forget easily. I do not believe in taking revenge or harming anyone. None of the people who harm me intentionally or unintentionally are answerable to me. They are all answerable to God and he will take care of them. Hence I have no heavy heart or ill feelings for anyone.

Does Person A want to tell me that I have hurt her or is she requesting me to let go of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context which you provided in your comments it seems that Person A is trying to convince you to let go of whatever happened between the two of you a year ago.

It also sounds like she is a little upset by you bringing up this issue a year after it happened but her words also suggest that she is trying to politely tell you to forget about what happened, forgive the person who did you wrong and leave the rest up to God.

Comment: It's all very much opinion-based, open to interpretation.  Often when someone is giving this type of "advice", they are trying to communicate their personal feelings/experiences, even if they don't intend to.

Comment: I agree @VictorBazarov I interpreted this question the way I would if someone told me what Person A had said.                                               I would assume that they are trying to give me some life advice but this could very well not be the case depending on what the context is(Did I do something wrong? Did I have a fight with Person A?, etc).

Comment: It is being told my ex-HR, we have very good relationship, but once she have done something wrong to me, may be under pressure of management, so I just call her and remind this thing like 1 yr ago you have done this kind of thing to me, and her response is something like this.

Comment: @KaranGandhi I think she is trying to tell you to let go of what happened. Just to be clear, you called her and reminded her of what happened a year ago and then she made her statement, correct?

Comment: I was afraid if she is get hurt by my act or angry on me, else I am very much okay.

Comment: After this statement she speak like, "Help urself first. let go everything and u will be peaceful rather than sitting and accusing and blaming thinking about it everytime"

Comment: @KaranGandh I don't think she would be hurt or angry, but she might be a little upset if you brought up something that happened a year ago. I have edited my answer, please mark it as accepted if it answers your question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31147/discussion-between-karan-gandhi-and-cucumber-boy).